# Are there any benefits to using GraphQL with React over using GraphQL with Vue/Ember/Angular?

Tags: angular, reactjs, vue.js, ember.js, graphql

Since GraphQL was developed by Facebook and React is also developed by Facebook I'm wondering if there are any benefits to using those two together as opposed to using a different javascript framework like Vue/Angular/Ember?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the GraphQL docs there's a definition of it:

> GraphQL is a query language for your API, and a server-side runtime for executing queries by using a type system you define for your data. GraphQL isn't tied to any specific database or storage engine and is instead backed by your existing code and data.
>
> https://graphql.org/learn/

First, GraphQL is not a technology but a query language.
Second, it's implemented on the back-end, hence it doesn't affect the front-end.

So there's no difference for the FE frameworks what's on the BE.